# JavaScript expand/collapse changing image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this piece of code

http://jsfiddle.net/nmggoqrg/

```
<div class="container">
<div class="header"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-right">Expand</span>

</div>
<div class="content">
    <ul>
        <li>This is just some random content.</li>
        <li>This is just some random content.</li>
        <li>This is just some random content.</li>
        <li>This is just some random content.</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

```
  $(".header").click(function () {

$header = $(this);
//getting the next element
$content = $header.next();
//open up the content needed - toggle the slide- if visible, slide up, if not slidedown.
$content.slideToggle(500, function () {
    //execute this after slideToggle is done
    //change text of header based on visibility of content div
    $header.text(function () {
        //change text based on condition
        return $content.is(":visible") ? "Expand -" : "Expand +";
    });
});
```

});

And would like some help, when clicking on expand, the page div expands to show the information. I would like for the header title to change from a right triangle to a bottom facing triangle. (the triangle being used are glyphicons from Bootstrap, the bottom arrow is "glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-bottom" class.)

I am a bit of a noob (and still learning) when it comes to JavaScript and do not know how to add css classes to JavaScript.

Is this possible?

Thank you

Comment: You haven't added .ready to your JQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the `span`, and just use [`addClass`](https://api.jquery.com/addClass/)/[`removeClass`](https://api.jquery.com/removeClass/) to change the icon.

```
$header = $(this);
$span = $(this).find('span.glyphicon');

if($content.is(':visible')){
    $span.removeClass('glyphicon-triangle-right');
    $span.addClass('glyphicon-triangle-bottom');
    $span.text('Expand -');
} else {
   $span.removeClass('glyphicon-triangle-bottom');
   $span.addClass('glyphicon-triangle-right');
   $span.text('Expand +');
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/daveSalomon/nmggoqrg/2/

With a bit of restructuring, you can make it more responsive...

```
  $(".header").click(function () {
    var $header = $(this);
    var $span = $header.find('span.glyphicon');
    var $content = $header.next('div.content');
    if($content.is(':visible')){
        $span.removeClass('glyphicon-triangle-bottom');
        $span.addClass('glyphicon-triangle-right');
    } else {
        $span.removeClass('glyphicon-triangle-right');
        $span.addClass('glyphicon-triangle-bottom');   
    }
    $content.slideToggle(500);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/daveSalomon/nmggoqrg/4/

You need to do something a little more clever to keep the arrow in sync if the user clicks the arrow multiple times quickly - perhaps you could use a combination of [`stop`](https://api.jquery.com/stop/) and using the callback as you were.

http://jsfiddle.net/daveSalomon/nmggoqrg/6/

Comment: Amazing, thank you for this. I am still learning the ropes with JavaScript. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Does [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nmggoqrg/1/) work for you?

Instead of replacing the $header content completely (which removes, among other things, the glyphicon contained inside), I only update the span.

```
// new
$header.find('.span').text(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery addClass() and removeClass() to get this.

```
     if($content.is(":visible"))
                        {
                            $("span").removeClass("glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down");
                            $("span").addClass("glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right");


                        }
                        else{
                            $("span").removeClass("glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right");
                            $("span").addClass("glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down");

                        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace the `text` and the `class` of the `span`. You can do this using [`.removeClass`](https://api.jquery.com/removeClass/) and [`.addClass`](https://api.jquery.com/addClass/).

Because the `span` is the only children, you can access it with [`.children`](https://api.jquery.com/children/). `

```
$span = $header.children();

$span.text(function () {
    //change text based on condition
    if($content.is(":visible")) { // replace with bottom
        $span.removeClass('glyphicon-triangle-right');
        $span.addClass('glyphicon-triangle-bottom');
        return  "Expand -";
    } else { // replace with right
        $span.removeClass('glyphicon-triangle-bottom');
        $span.addClass('glyphicon-triangle-right');
        return  "Expand +";
    }
});
```

The full code is in the working snnipe below.

```js
$(".header").click(function () {

    $header = $(this);
    //getting the next element
    $content = $header.next();
    $span = $header.children();
    //open up the content needed - toggle the slide- if visible, slide up, if not slidedown.
    $content.slideToggle(500, function () {
        //execute this after slideToggle is done
        //change text of header based on visibility of content div
        
        $span.text(function () {
            //change text based on condition
            if($content.is(":visible")){
                $span.removeClass('glyphicon-triangle-right');
                $span.addClass('glyphicon-triangle-bottom');
                return  "Expand -";
            }else {          
                $span.removeClass('glyphicon-triangle-bottom');
                $span.addClass('glyphicon-triangle-right');
                return  "Expand +";
            }
        });
    });

});
```

```css
.container {
    width:100%;
    border:1px solid #d3d3d3;
}
.container div {
    width:100%;
}
.container .header {
    background-color:#d3d3d3;
    padding: 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.container .content {
    display: none;
    padding : 5px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="header"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-right">Expand</span>

    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <ul>
            <li>This is just some random content.</li>
            <li>This is just some random content.</li>
            <li>This is just some random content.</li>
            <li>This is just some random content.</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use toggleClass also  like this

```
  $(".header").click(function () {
    $header = $(this);
    $content = $header.next();
    $content.slideToggle(500);
    $header.find('.glyphicon').toggleClass('glyphicon-triangle-right');
    $header.find('.glyphicon').toggleClass('glyphicon-triangle-bottom');
  });
```

link is provided here:   http://jsfiddle.net/nmggoqrg/5/